# Reputation for Deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, reputation, deleted-answers

Why there is a change in reputation both positive or negative when an answer is deleted ? If someone posts an arguably incorrect answer and people down vote that answer then that down vote should be retained . It has become so easy that someone posts an answer which reduces his/her reputation but one can negate that reduction by deleting the answer , otherwise if it is retained one will be more cautious and logical while posting an answer . Just my thought , it would be wonderful if we can implement this feature .

Comment: If you delete too many negatively voted answers, you will be answer-banned.

Comment: Is this a question or request? I can't rightly tell. I short, to answer: just because. On the other, curiosity-driven hand, I tend to agree that the economy of reputation is a very strange one, and not comparable to any kind of real world (or even virtual) economy or currency, which I do find peculiar (in concern for stability and meaningfullness of the thing).

Comment: What is the count and does moderator make sure to adhere to this rule or is it is done by system ?

Comment: Moderators don't manage nor do they have the ability to edit peoples reputation.

Comment: I would see convincing people to delete bad/incorrect answers as a good thing.

Comment: They can EDIT it to a correct answer as well rather than deleting it ;)

Comment: @BenBarden: Delete bad answers: Yes. Delete incorrect answers: Maybe...maybe not. Depends on the answer, an incorrect and downvoted answer can be as informative as a correct upvoted one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of the voting system is to give *notoriety* or to *disprove* an answer/question.
If the answer was so bad that the poster had to delete it, why should he keep the penality since the answer is no longer in the answer feed and therefore, no longer misleading people consulting that question ?

Bad answer should definitively be deleted and I think taking back the penality is a good way of encouraging the act of removing the answer.

An incorrect answer that received down-votes or negative comments can be edited and then reviewed by users and have the chance to get up-voted after. I think the voting/penality system works just fine this way.